# Merging 2 config files

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-config

I have a web application that is deployed with web.config file. Are there any tools/ pre-written deployment code that allows merging 2 web.config files including sections? If there is a section already existing, it should just merge the contents

Thanks in advance. Any guidance is much appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [XmlConfigMerge](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7406/XmlConfigMerge-Merge-config-file-settings)

> The XmlConfigMerge utility (provided both as a library assembly and as
>   a console application) supports this merging of XML .config files, and
>   also supports setting of specific parameters via XPath filtering and
>   optional Regex pattern matching.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any merge tool.
Here's one example - SourceGear Merge

http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at transformations:

[Managing web.config files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625090/managing-web-config-files)

Similar questions here:

[Managing web.config files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625090/managing-web-config-files)

[Using different Web.config in development and production environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305447/using-different-web-config-in-development-and-production-environment)

Comment: Not between environments. GP release to multiple deployments and upgrade their config with appends etc. Checkout Byranmac's solution